# Unwanted newlines appearing after concatenation

Tags: c, concatenation, newline

I have this code

```
    char output[1000] = "";
    int numWords = 0;
    int wordsRemoved = 0;
    char word[50]; // word that needs to be removed
    char ch; //character directly following the word being checked (always space or newline)
    char check[50]; // word that is being checked

    scanf("%s", word);


    while(!feof(stdin)){
        scanf("%s%c", check, &ch);
        numWords++; //counting total words

        if(strcmp(check, word) == 0){
            wordsRemoved++; //counting words removed
        }

        if(strcmp(word, check) != 0){
            strcat(output, check);   //checks if word should be removed and if not appends to str
            strncat(output, &ch, 1);
        }else if(strcmp(word, check) == 0 && ch == '\n'){
            strncat(output, &ch, 1);  // supposed to print a newline if the delete word was
                                      // on the end of a string but it gives me too many
                                      // newlines, and not enough if I remove it
        }
    }
    printf("%s", output); //prints new string

    return 0;
```

which is supposed to take an input text file and read until end of file, then remove a word specified by the user and then print the new string back out

For example, the test text file I am using reads:

```
cs
cs hello there
hello there cs
cs
hello there cscs there cs.
cs cs cs
test
```

Then the output should be

```
hello there
hello there
hello cscs there cs.
test
```

but I am instead getting

```
hello there
hello there

hello cscs there cs.

test
```

As you can see, I'm very close to figuring this out, but any line that consists of just the delete word ends up with an extra unwanted newline that I cannot figure out how to circumvent

Any idea how to get around this?

Also I am still learning to code so please don't use anything crazy advanced :)

Thanks for your help

Comment: if you want to remove empty lines, you should keep track of whether you have already printed anything on the current line. If you see a newline, print it only if your word counter is positive, then reset the counter to zero.

Comment: Not related to your empty lines but you might want to take a closer look at [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: @MOehm I tried using your advice to fix my problem but I'm not entirely sure if it is doing anything. I tried adding a condition to the if statement to only concatenate the newline if numWords was greater than zero (if(ch == '\n' && strcmp(word, check) == 0 && numWords > 0)), but the output didn't change, did I misunderstand your advice or doing something wrong?

Comment: [Here](https://ideone.com/yw91cz) is some code that does what you want. Printing a word and printing the space or newline are treated separately: If you must decide whether to print a newline or not, check whether you have written any words on the current line; if you must decide whether to print a space or not, check whether you have written the last word.

Comment: (That code uses `fscan(f, ...`)` to read from a file in memory, so that everything is contained in the example, you can replace that with `scanf`'s. It also prints instead of concatenating, because `strcat`ting to a fixed-size buffer from potentially infinite input is a recipe for disaster. The word to skip is hardcoded to make the example easier.)